# Fantasy movie involving crystals. It starts off with a girl making a wish on a birthday cake

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie when I was a child (5-7 years of age) so I don't remember much other than two scenes.

**The intro**

It starts off with a birthday cake and a girl wishing her wish on the birthday cake. Then the wish is sent up into constellations (I don't remember if it was *on the constellations* but it definitely got sent above)

**The climax(?)**

They managed to retrieve their sibling (Sister? Friend?) From the villain and is unconscious, there were two females fighting (I think it was about how to revive the unconscious one) and then one of the girls notices a crystal and then all of them suddenly thought of the idea to use their crystals to revive the unconscious one.

Comment: Labyrinth perhaps? What year was it?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In particular, what year did you watch this? What were the names of the girls? Was this live-action or animation? Was this in colour or black-and-white? Was this a film aimed at adults (with sex/violence/gore) or kids? What did the crystals look like? What colour was the birthday cake? How old were the girls? Did they have parents in the film? Who was the villain? How did you know that they were the villain (did they do or say something villainous?) What did the 'wish' look like (was it all sparkly or some sort of CGI effect)?

Comment: I dont remember the year and the names, it was animation, it was in color, it was aimed for children, the crystals have different colors for each siblings, i think the color of the cake was pink with the frosting of white and a cherry on top but im not sure, i dont remember how old they are, i also dont know who was the villain but i do know that there was a villain, i also dont think there were parents in the movie, it was like a wishing star or thay shiny thing from tinker bell

Comment: You could provide a rough estimate of the year by subtracting six from your current age. That would be very helpful. Several plot elements fit with Tangled, but there are also a number that do not. Do you think your memory might have 'mashed' two separate films into one?